# how to create ul li autocomplete input using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How to create ul/li autocomplete input using pure javascript without jquery.do not use option only ul/li.

Comment: what is your input and output?how about a demo or sample?

Comment: This sounds a lot like you're asking for homework answers, which is not the point of this site. If you're not, please look over [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure you're following the suggestions listed there. We're here to help you solve specific issues with your code, not write all the code for some particular task for you.  If you've already tried some things, please post the code you've tried, why you think it's having trouble (if you have any theories), and ask a specific question about the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example. You need a input box and `ul` & `li` to show the list. Use array `filter` method to find the element which matches with the input.

```js
var listOfCountries = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus"]

function updateValue(inputText) {
  document.getElementById('suggestionList').innerHTML = ''
  var filterElement = listOfCountries.filter(function(item) {
    return item.indexOf(inputText) !== -1
  }).forEach(function(item) {
    var _li = document.createElement('li');
    var content = document.createTextNode(item);
    _li.appendChild(content);
    document.getElementById('suggestionList').appendChild(_li)
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" onkeyup="updateValue(this.value)">
  <ul id="suggestionList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much, that is what I looking for. You have picked the same thing. @brk