# How to show autocomplete options under the box that the options are typed?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to show autocomplete options under the box that the options are typed? With the code below, the options are shown on the right side.

label has `display: flex` so that the text "Category" displays on the left side of the input. This is what messes it up.

```
 <label>
   Category
  <input type="text" value="a">
   <span class="autocomplete">
      <ul class="autocomplete-items">
         <li class="">Alligator</li>
         <li>Bask</li>
         <li>Crocodilian</li>
         <li>Death Roll</li>
         <li>Jaws</li>
         <li>Solitary</li>
         <li>Tail</li>
         <li>Wetlands</li>
      </ul>
   </span>
</label>
```

and css

```
  .autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: none;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
      label {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp

Comment: @LV98 My css code is very similar to the link you posted. However, its probably because my items are in ul/li and everything inside a label that it does not work. I expect  left 0 to position the options under the box.

Comment: This answer might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635401/9476349

Comment: @PatricNox I fixed it by removing display:flex but I know that all along just like in the link you provided. I was trying to keep display:flex on the parent label but still make this work.